# Render button in child component only on certain screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-component

Im using a flat list on 2 different screens. 
On the `EventListScreen`:
this is the main screen and should display all events.
and on the 2nd page `UserProfile.js` this page should only display that users events.
in both flat lists I'm using a pure component stored in a seperate class, to where the flat lists are i.e

My Question is, I want to display an "Edit" button on the `Event.js` child component only if the User is on the
`UserProfileScreen.js`

I have looked up a lot of example but cant really find any that show how to do it
with a child pure component like I'm doing.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

**EventListScreen.js**

```
  <FlatList
                data={this.state.events}
                // Get the item data by referencing as a new function to it
                renderItem={({item}) =>
                    <Event
                    openEventDetail={() => this.openEventDetail(item)}
                    {...item}
                    />}
            />
```

**UserProfileScreen.js**

```
  <FlatList
                data={this.state.events}
                // Get the item data by referencing as a new function to it
                renderItem={({item}) =>
                    <Event
                        openEventDetail={() => this.openEventDetail(item)}
                        openEditEvent={() => this.openEditEvent(item)}

                        {...item}
                    />}
            />
```

**Event.js**

```
export default class Event extends Component {

render() {

    return (
        <Card>
            <CardSection>
                <Text>{this.props.eventName}</Text>

                 //I want this button to be displayed only if user is viewing
                 //from the UserProfile.js
                <Button onPress={() =>this.props.openEditEvent()}>
                    {this.props.displayButton}
                </Button>

            </CardSection>

            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => this.props.openEventDetail()}
            >
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need additional properties.

We can assume that the "Edit" button should be available when `openEditEvent` prop is defined.

Condition in `event` (using convertion to bool, false for undefined):

```
        <CardSection>
            <Text>{this.props.eventName}</Text>

            {!!this.props.openEditEvent &&
              <Button onPress={() =>this.props.openEditEvent()}>
                {this.props.displayButton}
              </Button>
            }

        </CardSection>
```

Use propTypes to define `openEditEvent` prop as a function, optional (not required).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer, I will try it out soon.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly an option to solve this problem would be to pass a boolean "showable prop" to show the edit button only when required:

**EventListScreen.js** (Stays the same, we don't show the edit button here)

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.events}
    // Get the item data by referencing as a new function to it
    renderItem={({item}) =>
        <Event
        openEventDetail={() => this.openEventDetail(item)}
        {...item}
        />}
/>
```

**UserProfileScreen.js** (we add the shouldShowEditButton prop to event in order to show the button)

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.events}
    // Get the item data by referencing as a new function to it
    renderItem={({item}) =>
        <Event
            openEventDetail={() => this.openEventDetail(item)}
            openEditEvent={() => this.openEditEvent(item)}
            shouldShowEditButton
            {...item}
        />}
/>
```

**Event.js** (We add some propTypes and defaultProps to handle the new prop, it won't show the edit button if not specified)

```
export default class Event extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <Card>
                <CardSection>
                    <Text>{this.props.eventName}</Text>

                     //I want this button to be displayed only if user is viewing
                     //from the UserProfile.js
                    {this.props.shouldShowEditButton && <Button onPress={() =>this.props.openEditEvent()}>
                        {this.props.displayButton}
                    </Button>}

                </CardSection>

                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => this.props.openEventDetail()}
                >
                ...
        ...
        );
    ...
    }
}

// We add some default propTypes and definitions
Event.propTypes = {
    shouldShowEditButton: PropTypes.bool
};

Event.defaultProps = {
    shouldShowEditButton: false
};
```

In this way you're only showing the edit button for the components that have the prop `shouldShowEditButton` defined, and because its default value is defined as `false`, the components that don't have the property will behave in the same way they were before.